# Use well-known relation: $\det(I + \epsilon X) = 1 + \operatorname{tr}(X) \epsilon + O(\epsilon^2).$ for evaluate $\det(I + M)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $d_1$, $d_2\in[0,1]$. Use well-known relation:
$$\det(I + \epsilon X) = 1 + \operatorname{tr}(X) \epsilon + O(\epsilon^2).$$
for evaluate
$$\det(I + M)$$
where $I$ is the $2\times2$ identity matrix and
$$M=\left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
    d_1(1-d_1) &\ \ \ \ \ d_1(1-d_2)  \\
    d_2(1-d_1) & d_2(1-d_2) \\
  \end{array}
\right)$$
I notice that $m_{ij}\in[0,1]$, for all $i,j=1,2$. But, what is $\epsilon$ in this case? Maybe could I take out of the matrix some parameters $d_i$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably $d_1$ and $d_2$ are each very close to either $0$ or $1$. Supposing they are both nearly zero, you can choose $\epsilon$ to be the bigger one, and then write $M=\epsilon (M/\epsilon)$. So supposing $d_1$ is the bigger one, you wind up with

$$\text{det}(I+M)=1+d_1 \text{tr} \left ( \begin{bmatrix} 1-d_1 & 1-d_2 \\ \frac{d_2(1-d_1)}{d_1} & \frac{d_2(1-d_2)}{d_1} \end{bmatrix} \right ) + O(d_1^2).$$

It is best to "factor" the bigger one so that the matrix whose trace you are taking remains bounded. Otherwise some additional cancellation is required to isolate the leading order correction term.

Alternately, your asymptotic equality is equivalent to $\text{det}(I+X)=I+\text{tr}(X)+O(\| X \|^2)$. Then by picking a matrix norm, you get an asymptotic. This approach is nice because it doesn't really care what the form of $X$ was, so for your situation it would work in any of the four possibilities I mentioned in my first sentence.